# PHP View file Is not able to access variable defined in Controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

I have been attempting to apply the model view controller approach to my php programming. I have a file that is simply building a select box using data from a MySQL database. The controller is able to pull the data using a static method from the model and the results can be "echo"ed successfully through the controller function. However when I try to loop through the array using the $artifactTypes variable (defined in the controller) in the view file, I am getting "Notice: Undefined variable: artifactTypes". I feel like there may be a scope issue that I am not seeing.

```
// model file - model/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox.php
//Queries the database pulling 11 types of artifacts
<?php
require('model/Db.class.php'); //parameters for pdo connection

class ArtifactClassSelectBox {

    public function __construct(){
    }

    static public function getArtifactClass(){
        try {
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT artifact_class
                FROM artifact_type";
                $db = Db::getInstance();
                $results = $db->prepare($query);
                $results->execute();
            $artifactClasses = array();
            while ($row = $results->fetch()){
                $a = $row['artifact_class'];
                array_push($artifactClasses, $a);
                }
            return $artifactClasses; 
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return "Unable to pull artifact classes from the Artifact Type table.<br/>";
                echo  $e->getMessage();
            }
    }
?>

//Controller File - controller/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox_Controller.php
<?php
require_once('./model/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox.Class.php');

class ArtifactSelectBoxController {
    public function artifactSelectBox(){
            require_once('view/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox.php');                    
             $artifactTypes = ArtifactClassSelectBox::getArtifactClass();
             /*foreach($artifactTypes as $ac){
                echo $ac . "<br />";
             }
            That pulls the 11 records successfully */
     }
 }
?>

//View File - view/Buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox.php
<label for='artifact_class'>Artifact Class</label>
<select name='artifact_class' id='artifact_class'>
   <?php 
       foreach($artifactTypes as $aC){ ?>
       <option value='<?php echo $aC; ?>' id='<?php echo $aC; ?>'><?php echo $aC; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>

//index.php - calls the controller
<?php
  require_once('controller/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox_Controller.php');
  $controller = new ArtifactSelectBoxController;
  $controller->artifactSelectBox();

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

[require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php), executes the `view` before the variable declaration.

You need to interchange the line, in `ArtifactSelectBoxController` class

From,

```
 require_once('view/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox.php');                    
 $artifactTypes = ArtifactClassSelectBox::getArtifactClass();
```

To,

```
 $artifactTypes = ArtifactClassSelectBox::getArtifactClass();
 require_once('view/buttons/ArtifactClassSelectBox.php');
```

Comment: Oh. So I was loading the file that called the variable before defining the variable. Thanks